# Record updated array after button selections (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

In this menu of buttons, a user can select multiple buttons and submit their final answer by clicking the done button. They can change their answer by unselecting buttons but again, their final answer should be submitted upon clicking the done button.

Currently, I'm able to record each button selection upon clicks and update the array along the way. However, I'd like to *only* record the final answer. Although I am recording locally to the console in this toy example, I am emitting data to a server in my real code.

I've commented out where I would have printed upon each click -- just leaving it there for explanatory clarity. Again I hope to only print the final answer upon the user clicking the done button. I think I'm encountering a scoping problem in that the "clicked" array doesn't exist outside the map function. But I don't know how to solve the problem. Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you to everyone in advance! (Also open to taking edit suggestions if anything is unclear!)

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #done {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="done">
      <p>done</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let $buttonGallery = $("#buttonGallery");
    let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];
    let clicked = [];

    myList.map(function(letter, index) {
      let clicked = [];
      let $button = $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("buttons")
        .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
        .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
        .on("mouseenter", function() {
          $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function() {
          if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).css("background", "transparent");
          }
        })
        .on("click", function() {
          $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
          $(this).toggleClass('selected');
          clicked = [];

          // push clicked variables to array
          let syms = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');

          for (let n = 0; n < syms.length; n++) {
            if (!clicked.includes(syms[n].textContent)) {
              clicked.push(syms[n].textContent);
            }
          };

          // send data to server
          // console.log('clicked array', clicked);
        })
      $("#done").before($button);
    });

    $("#done").on("click", clearColor);

    function clearColor() {
      console.log('clicked array', clicked);

      $(".buttons").css({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      });
      $(".buttons").removeClass('selected');

      // reset clicked list after recording button selections
      clicked = [];
    }
  </script>
</body>
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `let clicked = []` in the map, so that becomes the `clicked` array in scope for adding the clicked values to. You add to that "inner" `clicked` array, but your `clearColor()` function was looking at the "outer" `clicked` array which stayed empty. You just need to remove the `let clicked = [];` line inside your `map()`

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style media="screen">
    .buttons {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }

    #buttonGallery {
      margin: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      width: 155px;
    }

    #done {
      width: 150px;
      height: 50px;
      border: solid 2px black;
      text-align: center;
      color: black;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: white;
      margin: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="buttonGallery">
    <div id="done">
      <p>done</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let $buttonGallery = $("#buttonGallery");
    let myList = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
    let myColors = ["red", "green", "blue", "red"];
    let clicked = [];

    myList.map(function(letter, index) {
      //let clicked = []; <-- don't re-declare it here
      let $button = $("<div></div>")
        .addClass("buttons")
        .attr("id", "button_" + letter)
        .html("<p>" + letter + "</p>")
        .on("mouseenter", function() {
          $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function() {
          if (!$(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).css("background", "transparent");
          }
        })
        .on("click", function() {
          $(this).css("background", myColors[index]);
          $(this).toggleClass('selected');
          clicked = [];

          // push clicked variables to array
          let syms = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');

          for (let n = 0; n < syms.length; n++) {
            if (!clicked.includes(syms[n].textContent)) {
              clicked.push(syms[n].textContent);
            }
          };

          // send data to server
          // console.log('clicked array', clicked);
        })
      $("#done").before($button);
    });

    $("#done").on("click", clearColor);

    function clearColor() {
      console.log('clicked array', clicked);

      $(".buttons").css({
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      });
      $(".buttons").removeClass('selected');

      // reset clicked list after recording button selections
      clicked = [];
    }
  </script>
</body>
</script>

</html>
```